# How to capture Cordova Log?

Tags: cordova

I am using PhoneGap and deploying it on android tablet. Using javascript. jQuery with Cordova plug in. I am debugging the app using CordovaLog. Can I capture that log and email it ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have your device connected to your machine (otherwise see other stackoverflow anwsers)

```
> adb devices
List of devices attached 
0xxxxxxxxxxx    device
```

You can see the logs with logcat. (this will go to the default connected device (usb or tcp) and show all Info messages)

```
> adb logcat
```

Probably more usefull is

```
> adb logcat -v time CordovaLog:V *:F
```

this puts the logs with tag CordovaLog on verbose filter and all other message on fatal.
All your log messages are put under the CordovaLog tag.

Pass this invalid option to see more detailed info on logcat

```
> adb logcat -?
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Linux using Cordova 3.

```
cordova emulate android && adb -s emulator-5554 logcat
```

Pipe to a file

```
cordova emulate android
adb -s emulator-5554 logcat > ~/debug.txt
```

Comment: The question was about installed apps and sending a logfile from the device.

Comment: As in reading the log on the device while it's running in the wild or while testing on your emulator? For the second, you can always pipe the logcat to a file.

Answer (score 0):

This Works for me in windows

adb logcat chromium:D SystemWebViewClient:D *:S